# string encoding, mobile encoding

Tags: android

I have a strings.xml file with all my app string, I have some simbols like €, and I having trouble with them.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
     <string name="currency"> € </string>
</resources></resources>
```

They usually shows fine, but not in all devices:

[image]

How can I auto-detect the configuration in the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, in the java class I had:

```
 webCost.loadData(cost, "text/html", null);
```

And it should be:

```
  webAbout.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, aboutStr, "text/html","utf-8", null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create string files for different languages. Please read "[Supporting Different Languages](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html)".

Answer (score 1):

You should use Unicode Character for Currency symbol.

so instead of

```
<string name="currency"> € </string>
```

use this one

```
 <string name="pound">\u00a3</string>
 <string name="euro">\u20ac</string>
```

This will uni formally look same in all the devices.
This will surely solve your issue.